# problem with ROS NXT

Tags: ros, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my name is Edgar and I'm new in ROS.
The problem is when I send *sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-nxtall* and also with electric version, terminal shows this message:

*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-nxtall*

How do I solve this.
I have Ubuntu 12.10 and ROS groovy installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62125/problem-with-ros-nxt/) by [emvela](https://answers.ros.org/users/4825/emvela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2013-05-08**:
Hi Edgar: My name is Ivan,our robotics group is writing some packages to NXT for Groovy version. When it is available if you want to notice you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), Diamondback was never released for Ubuntu 12.10, so you can't install the NXT stack on your Ubuntu version.

According to [wiki/nxt](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt), the NXT stack is currently only build for Electric.

I see two options:

1. go back to an Ubuntu version where Electric can be installed: most recent version would be Oneiric (11.10), according to [REP 003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).
2. check out the sources for the NXT stack and try to build it for Fuerte or Groovy. AFAIK the NXT stack hasn't really been maintained, so this might be rather difficult.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0